# C# Outlook 2007 Event actual viewed Mail Changes

Tags: c#, outlook

I'm coding an Outlook Add-In for Outlook 2007/2010 with c#.
Is there any event or a possibility to code something, which will be executed when the actual viewed mail changes?

For example... on the right side should be a sidebar showing contact information about the sender and this have to be refreshed every time I view another mail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `Explorer.SelectionChanged` event to notify your addin that the user has selected a new item.

[Here is the MSDN documentation.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869813.aspx)

You would hook into this event on your addins startup method like this:

```
private void ThisApplication_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)

{
    this.ActiveExplorer().SelectionChange += () => {    
        MessageBox.Show("Selection Changed")
    };
}
```